# How can we use the abstract getScreenSize() method in Toolkit class?

Tags: awt, toolkit, java

Searching on java api document, i found that the getScreenSize() method is an abstract method in the Toolkit class. Now i'm wondering why the code below works.

```
Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
setLocation((d.width - getWidth())/2,(d.height - getHeight())/2);
```

if getScreenSize() is abstract, then we shouldn't be able to use it. How does it work?

Comment: `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit` returns an implementation of `Toolkit` specific for the OS - this is all done internally and is an example of polymorphism - the point is, you don't care about "how" or "what" the implementation is, you only care that it upholds the contract defined by `Toolkit`

Comment: Looks like that should be an answer, but there's probably a dup somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit` will return a subclass of `Toolkit` which implements `getScreenSize()` appropriately. It's defined as abstract in `Toolkit` so that the behavior can be defined separately for different platforms.